# Update data in LINQ with Object instead of set properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

I want to update my data with object instead of set properties. below is simple example for understanding my question really i am stuck in big problem on updating data

```
Employee emp_old = new Employee();
emp_old.ID = 1 ;
emp_old.Name = "Muzammil";

Employee emp_new = new Employee();
emp_new.ID = 1 ;
emp_new.Name = "Ahmed";

Employee temp = db.Employees.single(emp => emp.ID == emp_old.ID);
temp = emp_new;
```

Comment: *below is simple example for understanding my question*. What is your question?

Comment: I guess the question is, instead of modifying each property the OP wants to set the object reference to a new existing object.

Comment: Do you want to set specific properties or all the properties?

Comment: Yes Habib you have understand my problem

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind this? You can use AutoMapper to copy property values from the new object to the old object in less code if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for [`CurrentValues.SetValues()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbpropertyvalues.setvalues(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
Employee emp_new = new Employee();
emp_new.ID = 1 ;
emp_new.Name = "Ahmed";

Employee temp = db.Employees.Find(1);
db.Entry(temp).CurrentValues.SetValues(emp_new);
```

This methods overwrites properties that both the target and the source object have in common (by name and type). Note that `emp_new` doesn't even have to be an `Employee` instance.